# Find the probability that all nodes are working, knowing that first node is down?

Tags: probability

We have *N* nodes each might go down with probability *p*. What is probability of running 2nd, ..., Nth node while 1st is down?

I thought it should be like:

$p*(1-p)^{N-1}$

but correct one is:

$(1-p)^{N-1}$

sorry for home work question, but I am really confused. Should it be calculated as a joint probability or otherwise.

Comment: If the question is to find probability that the first node is down but all others working, your answer is correct. But if the question is to find probability of all other nodes working _given_ the first node is down then the official answer is correct. The second is conditional probability. Please check  Bayes' theorem.

Comment: @MathLover thanks for answer. Is there any difference if the 1st node is down or one of the arbitrary nodes is down?

Comment: if any _specific_ node is down, it is the same but if it is any one of the nodes then it is different